# Sphere inscribed in a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

A sphere is inscribed within a regular tetrahedron with sides of length 6. What is the area of any given great circle of the sphere?

My solution: Using similar triangles, I came up with the ratio on the picture. However, this was marked incorrect. Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Comment: It seems that you think that the sphere is tangent to the edge of the tetrahedron.

Comment: Yes as I thought that was the main way for the sphere to be inscribed the tetrahedron? Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: A sphere inscribed in a tetrahedron is tangent to the four faces of the tetrahedron, not its edges.

Comment: @GeometryLover Using that information, would it be possible for you to show me how to set up how to do this problem?

Comment: The centroid of the regular tetrahedron lies at $\dfrac{h}{4}$ above its base, where $h$ is the altitude of the tetrahedron.  So the radius of inscribed sphere is just $\dfrac{h}{4}$, and the altitude is $h = a \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}$ where $a$ is the side length.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!

Comment: The inscribed sphere touches the centre of each of the faces of the tetrahedron. In your cross section triangle the sphere should touch the base at the face centre (i.e. at the bottom of that vertical line), and will also touch the left side of the triangle, but will not touch the right side. That right side is an edge of the tetrahedron and does therefore not go through a face centre. Your method for solving it would work if you only applied it to the left side of the triangle instead of the right.

Comment: Excellent shortcut offered by GeometryLover. The $\frac {h}{4}$ centroid height actually goes for any pyramid or cone. I was going to offer a method of my own, but it would have required at least twice the number of steps.